# Change download location for Inno Setup TDownloadWizardPage

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript, inno-setup-v6

I'm using Inno Setup's download system, but I would like to change the download folder from `{tmp}` to another one, can someone help me?

of:

```pascal
DownloadPage.Add('{#LinkJava}', ExpandConstant('{tmp}\Java.exe'), '');
```

for:

```pascal
DownloadPage.Add('{#LinkJava}', ExpandConstant('{src}{#PastaGeralDeApps}{#PastaDownPlugins}{#NomeExeJava}'), '');
```

I'm creating an automatic installer and I need to store the apps in a folder, to use offline.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the folder, where the files are downloaded to using `TDownloadWizardPage` (note that the `BaseName` argument of `TDownloadWizardPage.Add` accepts a filename only, not a path).

But you can copy over the files to the final folder, once they are downloaded.

```
[Files]
Source: "{tmp}\downloaded-file.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; flags: external
```

You of course need to download the files before the actual installation. So for example from [`NextButtonClick(wpReady)`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=NextButtonClick), the way the [official `CodeDownloadFiles.iss` example](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/main/Examples/CodeDownloadFiles.iss) does.

---

If you need to move the files to the final location before the installation, use [`RenameFile`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_renamefile) or [`FileCopy`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_filecopy) functions. The copying is obviously slower, but more reliable, as you cannot move/rename between disks/filesystems. You might try moving, falling back to copying, if moving fails.

Comment: I followed your tip and managed to solve it by creating a new function as you mentioned, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

```
//function that performs the download - OK
function DownloadFiles(Url, Destination, FileName, Hash : String): Boolean;
begin
    DownloadPage.Clear;    
    DownloadPage.Add(Url, FileName, Hash);     
    DownloadPage.Show;
    try
      try
        DownloadPage.Download;
        Result := True;
      except
        if DownloadPage.AbortedByUser then
          Log('Aborted by user.')
        else
          SuppressibleMsgBox(AddPeriod(GetExceptionMessage), mbCriticalError, MB_OK, IDOK);
        Result := False;
      end;
    finally
      FileCopyLogged(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\'+FileName), ExpandConstant(Destination+'\'+FileName), False);      
    end;
    Result := True;     
end;
```

Comment: Consider referring to the implementation of `FileCopyLogged` and doing error checking there. + In general it might be worth trying move first, instead of copy. But I understood that you copy to an USB drive, so moving cannot succeed. + You might want to delete the unneeded file from the `{tmp}` right after copying it, instead of waiting for Inno Setup to do it for you at the end, not to run out of disk space, if you have several downloads.