# Modify default path in Inno Setup 'Setup Needs the Next Disk' prompt

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

My program's size is larger than 2GB. So, I set the `DiskSpanning` option to true and uploaded the divided 'bin' files to 'S3'. The 'bin' files are automatically downloaded to the `tmp` folder. I failed to move or copy files to 'Downloads' folder and failed to change default path in *'Setup Needs the Next Disk'* printed 'Installing' previous wizard. So I would like to know how to change the default path or move the files in `tmp` to the 'Downloads' folder.
Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change the path and the default path is not the *"Downloads"* folder either. The default path is the location of the installer .exe file. Basically the [`{src}`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts&anchor=src).

For moving the downloaded files elsewhere, see:
[Change download location for Inno Setup TDownloadWizardPage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67992701/850848)